# Refreshing Grails applicationContext

Tags: java, spring, grails

In my configuration's spring/resources.xml file, I define a bean like this :

```
<bean id="myService" class="org.springframework.remoting.caucho.HessianProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="http://${remote.host}:8080/MyAgent/remoting/MyService"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="services.MyService"/>
</bean>
```

In my Config.groovy file I have :
remote.host = "someipaddress"

Now I'd like to change this placeholder's value at runtime. In a regular spring app, I do this through a PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer, then I refresh the context and it works.

In Grails, how can I refresh the context ?

Regards,

Philippe

Comment: If I didn't get you wrong, you're asking how to refresh the context (you can always restart the server, or re-deploy the app - as you're not changing the setup every day), but the primary issue is how to replace `remote.host` without recompilation. - Is that correct?

Comment: Nope... it's to replace remote.host dynamically whenever I want because I will be connecting to several remote services hosted on different hosts. (yeah I know maybie this shouldn't be a singleton but that does not solve my refresh problem...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I give up the refreshing approach.
As a workaround, I created a grails service that looks like this :

```
class myService {
    def myRemoteService
    static transactional = false

    private MyRemoteService getService(String remoteServiceURL) {
        HessianProxyFactory factory = new HessianProxyFactory();
        try {
            return (MyRemoteService) factory.create(MyRemoteService.class, url);
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return null
    }

    def someRemoteMethod(String remoteServiceURL) {
        getService(remoteServiceURL).myRemoteMethod()
    }
}
```

This allows me to invoke the remote service on any distant machine dinamically.

I'm still interested in a cleaner solution as this makes me rewrite a wrapper method for each remote method :-S

Answer (score 0):

Why not just update the value directly:

```
def blabla
...
void someServiceMethod() {
   blabla.someProperty = 'new value'
}
```

or

```
def blabla
...
def someControllerAction = {
   blabla.someProperty = 'new value'
}
```

Comment: Well that's true, but in my case the bean is in fact a dynamic proxy (org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy), so I don't have direct access to the fields of the proxied interface.

Answer (score 0):

[grailsApplication](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.x/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/GrailsApplication.html) expose a refresh() method, i'm not sure if it will reload spring context, you could try.

Comment: Well, grailsApplication.mainContext should be refreshable, but I get this : 2010-11-26 12:10:27,841 [http-8080-1] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - GenericApplicationContext does not support multiple refresh attempts: just call 'refresh' once
java.lang.IllegalStateException: GenericApplicationContext does not support multiple refresh attempts: just call 'refresh' once
 at ServiceUrlFilters$_closure1_closure3_closure5.doCall(ServiceUrlFilters:33)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick search in grails mailing list, and looks like grails do not support app-context reload.

You could try implement InitializingBean and get the values direct from app config.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean

class ExampleService implements InitializingBean { 

   def grailsApplication 
   def setting

   void afterPropertiesSet() { 
      this.setting = grailsApplication.config.setting 
   }
}
```

Maybe you can listen for changes in the config or get the property every time you need to use it, i do not know, i can not create a app to run some tests right now.

Comment: Thanks, but my service is not defined as a Grails service I can control in my application. It's a java service deployed on a remote tomcat, exposed through Hessian. In my grails app I only have the service interface and I configure access to the remote service through a HessianProxyFactoryBean...

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but try:

```
import grails.spring.BeanBuilder

def bb = new BeanBuilder(
        application.parentContext,
        new GroovyClassLoader(application.classLoader))
def beans = bb.beans {
    myService(org.springframework.remoting.caucho.HessianProxyFactoryBean) {
        ...
    }
}
beans.registerBeans(application.mainContext)
```

This is pretty much what plugins do when they need to swap in new bean instances. You could also raise a JIRA issue for a nicer way of doing this.

Comment: What is the difference of this approach in terms of being able to refresh the context at runtime ?

Comment: Two differences:

1. You can register entirely new beans for a given ID
2. It works, whereas .refresh() apparently doesn;t, although I haven't tested that.